# Kendo UI Grid Anuglar Cell Color

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an Angular 2 App using the Kendo UI Grid. There I have a Grid showing some data (integer values). Is it possible, to colorize each cell according to it's type? Maybe adding css class to each cell based on the type?

right now, the data looks like this [{"a":4,"b"=35,...},{...},....] I also have types for each element but not yet saved in the data grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion it's still in form of pure js kendo (but you should be able to do it in angular 2 kendo), by using schema.parse or in **angular 2 : after getting data from backend** you could add additionals field in the after retrieving your data from rest endpoint. add your logic inside the looping in my case i just assign color at random

```
schema: {
    parse : function(response){
      var colors = [
          'red',
          'green',
          'blue',
          'yellow'
      ];
      //loop through all you data, add adding aditional field. 
      //also here i randomize the color for each cell
      for(var i = 0; i< response.d.results.length; i++){
        response.d.results[i].cell1 = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        response.d.results[i].cell2 = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        response.d.results[i].cell3 = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        response.d.results[i].cell4 = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
      }

      return response
    }
}
```

Then on the row template you could use it as class like this (look at the cell1,cell2,cell3,cell4 attribute) in [kendo-angular2 reference detail row template](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/detail-template/) :

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr data-uid="#: uid #">
        <td class="photo #=data.cell1#">
           <img src="../content/web/Employees/#:data.EmployeeID#.jpg" alt="#: data.EmployeeID #" />
        </td>
        <td class="details #=data.cell2#">
           <span class="name">#: FirstName# #: LastName# </span>
           <span class="title">Title: #: Title #</span>
        </td>
    <td class="country #=data.cell3#">
            #: Country #
        </td>
        <td class="employeeID #=data.cell4#">
           #: EmployeeID #
        </td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

then add the css

```
<style>
    .red {
      background-color: red;  
    }
    .green {
      background-color: green;  
    }
    .blue {
      background-color: blue;  
    }
    .yellow {
      background-color: yellow;  
    }
</style>
```

Working example in [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UqiFIB)